# cannot write to file in magento rest api

Tags: rest-api, magento-2.1.7

I'm building rest api to write to json file but I get

```
This path not writable
```

here is the code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $ioFile = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $dirPath = $ioFile->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::APP);
    $dirPath->writeFile("code/Vendor/Module/Model/Product/file.json",json_encode($arr));
```

what is the problem?. If it's a permission problem can you explain the problem

Comment: does the path to the file exist?

Comment: writeing to the app folder is a bad partice... use var or tmp

Comment: @PhilippSander yes, it exists. And why this is bad practice?

Comment: app is dedicated for code and design files. file in app are checked in your VCS. what's the benefit of having it in app instead of var?